# Можно ли написать запроc sql - нужно сделать группировку по вложенному запросу

Tags: sql

Помогите написать запрос sql.
Есть 2 таблицы - Message 1 и Message 2. В каждой из тих таблиц есть столбец Статус.
Необходимо узнать какой тип Статуса встречается в обеих таблицах, а какой в одной.
Результат должен быть таким: 2 столбца, в 1-м - название статуса, во 2-м - значение "1" если статус есть только в одной таблице, и значение "2", если статус есть в обеих таблицах.

Comment: Что пробовали? что не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Вот таким запросом можно осуществить желаемую выборку:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT m1.status FROM Message1 m1
  GROUP BY m1.status
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m2.status FROM Message2 m2
  GROUP BY m2.status
) x
GROUP BY x.status;
```

Запрос сначала отберет из двух таблиц уникальные статусы, а далее посчитает, сколько раз данные представлены в выборке.

Если 2, значит есть в 2-х таблицах, если 1, значит только в одной.